# Extracting first degree neighbors from a file

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a very big file have edges with some numerical attributes (gene-gene correlation values.

```
Solyc06g071220.1.1 Solyc03g119900.3.1 -0.103908702731133 0.84469789799632
Solyc06g021220.1.1 Solyc06g082440.1.1 -0.224259048700333 0.669250658547268
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc03g062750.1.1 0.71688175201416 0.108887108533016
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc04g055160.3.1 0.0175280850380659 0.973710565052682
Solyc06g041220.1.1 Solyc09g065990.3.1 0.390961289405823 0.443437425098591
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc01g109440.2.1 -0.19314156472683 0.713890096929684
Solyc06g071220.1.1 Solyc06g065310.3.1 -0.0117298867553473 0.982405976825965
Solyc06g071220.1.1 Solyc04g078470.3.1 -0.325205653905869 0.529388185554353
Solyc06g071220.1.1 Solyc01g008510.3.1 0.7591872215271 0.0800037292660498
Solyc04g078470.3.1 Solyc06g031220.1.1 0.891855001449585 0.0169106147650597
Solyc04g055160.3.1 Solyc06g031220.1.1 0.0175280850380659 0.973710565052682
```

given another file input.txt, it should be able to extract all its neighbors:

**Input.txt**

```
Solyc06g031220.1.1
```

Output:

```
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc03g062750.1.1 0.71688175201416 0.108887108533016
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc04g055160.3.1 0.0175280850380659 0.973710565052682
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc01g109440.2.1 -0.19314156472683 0.713890096929684
Solyc04g078470.3.1 Solyc06g031220.1.1 0.891855001449585 0.0169106147650597
Solyc04g055160.3.1 Solyc06g031220.1.1 0.0175280850380659 0.973710565052682
```

Since the network is undirected, A-B and B-A are same and should be removed.

I had done the python way i.e. split each line based on space, and checked the presence of the gene ids in the first two list elements. But this is taking a very log time to traverse the file. Kindly help

```
file1=open("correlation_v1.txt", 'r')
file2=open("input.txt", "r")

file1_id=file1.readlines()
file2_id=file2.readlines()

for i in file1_id:
    gene_id=i.split()
    gene_id[0]=gene_id[0].strip()
    gene_id[1]=gene_id[1].strip()
    for j in file2_id:
        loc_id=j.split()
        loc_id[0]=loc_id[0].strip()
        if ((loc_id[0] == gene_id[0]) or (loc_id[0] == gene_id[1])):
            print i,"\t", j
```

Comment: Can't you just do this with `grep`?

Comment: You did something in python but it was too slow? Show what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *Since the network is undirected, A-B and B-A are same and should be removed* means that in case of:

```
A B 1 2
B A 1 2
```

output should be

```
A B 1 2
```

The awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {s=$0; next } 
($1==s||$2==s) && ($1!=a[$2]&&$2!=a[$1]) {
    a[$1]=$2
    a[$2]=$1
    print
}' <(echo A) file
```

outputs:

```
A B 1 2
```

Output with your data (`awk '...' input.txt file`):

```
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc03g062750.1.1 0.71688175201416 0.108887108533016
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc04g055160.3.1 0.0175280850380659 0.973710565052682 # this is a duplicate
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc01g109440.2.1 -0.19314156472683 0.713890096929684
Solyc06g031220.1.1 Solyc04g078470.3.1 -0.325205653905869 0.529388185554353
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily with `grep`:

```
grep -F -w -f input.txt filename
```

`-F` makes it look for literal strings instead of a regexp pattern. `-w` makes it look for the string as a whole word. And `-f` makes it take the pattern to search for from the input file.

Comment: yes, thank you I was trying with grep but did not know about '-w'

Comment: This does not satisfy requirement: _Since the network is undirected, A-B and B-A are same and should be removed_ (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: Removing those duplicates can easily be done by post-processing after matching.